# Why Node JS application shows increased memory usage after 6 days of continuous running?

Tags: node.js, memory-management

I am using NodeJS for production and deployed in behind Nginx in a digital ocean server. I have an Express JS based web server. Which when I started was using 18% memory. Now the memory stands at 49%, post six days. I would like to know if the memory is being leaked in NodeJS? How do I do memory profiling in NodeJS and come at an exact conclusion that all the objects that are being created are being safely cleaned up V8? Or is it normal for applications to show increased memory usage? If yes Why? If No, Could there be other reason then memory leakage in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are look for [v8-profiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-profiler).